# What method can be used to specifically insert data into your C# DataGridView from SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

Problem:

Code works fine, however, when I launch my program my two predefined columns `Course_ID` and `File_Count` are present in my then blank dataGridView. There is also an empty default row.

Whenever I run my query, my dataGridView is getting an extra column created and an extra row created. The result from the query goes into this new third column on the first row which is weird.

See here:

http://imgur.com/UBFI8Nz

Here is my code:

```
string[] courses = txtBoxCourses.Text.Split(',');

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=userid;" +
                                   "password=password;server=myserver;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=no;" +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

        myConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();           
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);     
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

        DataTable t = new DataTable();

        foreach (string line in courses) 
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = "DECLARE @CourseName varchar(80); Set @CourseName = '"+line+"' SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT FILE_ID,PARENT_ID ,PATH_ID,FULL_PATH ,FILE_NAME FROM BBLEARN_cms_doc.dbo.XYF_URLS WHERE FULL_PATH like '/courses/'+@CourseName+'/%') as subquery;";
            adapter.Fill(t);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
        }
```

What I want to happen is I want to fill in the first column with the values from my `string[] courses` list and I want it to correspond with the result from the query in my `foreach` statement. For example, if I use two course IDs to query, `test1` and `test2` I'd prefer this:

```
Course_ID   file_count
    test1       234
    test2      1478
```

I've looked into using the `DataPropertyName` property but I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your select to:

```
SELECT @CourseName as Course_ID, COUNT(*) as File_Count FROM ( 
SELECT FILE_ID,PARENT_ID ,PATH_ID,FULL_PATH ,FILE_NAME FROM BBLEARN_cms_doc.dbo.XYF_URLS
WHERE FULL_PATH like '/courses/'+@CourseName+'/%') as subquery;
```

Your current query is returning an integer and your grid view doesn't see it attached to any of your predefined columns.  Try aliasing the columns with the column name in the grid view.  That should tie your sql results to your current columns.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce There should be.  Best guess is that you have insert enabled for the GridView.  It is giving you a blank row so you can enter data and save a new row.  The other option is that you are getting a null record from your sql statement.  You can debug visual studio and see when your data table gets a null row.  If your data table gets an null row, figure out what sql statement generated it.  If no null row, the grid view is doing it.  Alos, I just noticed that your foreach loop fills the data table  and grid view each time in the loop.  Set the data source once outside the loop.

Comment: I noticed that before coming back to the question and already fixed it. good call!